# How to email sharepoint Online list items as a excel spreadsheet attachment

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

On the 20th of each month, I need an email to go to 2 users with an excel attachment that contains the details of a specific SharePoint Online list.

Is this possible to set up?

Thank you for your assistance!